# how to split text of a JSON file into pieces using C#

Tags: c#, json

I am having a JSON file like this:

```
[
    {
        Object0
        ...
    },
    {
        Object1
        ...
    },
    ...
    {
        Objectn
        ...
    }
]
```

How to split the text into peices of { Object } string?
I mean a collection of string, such as string[] or List, espected output is for each of string there is something like this:

```
{
    text
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by pieces. Do you want it be stores in a collection

Comment: Please add output example, it's difficult to understand what you expect to get

Comment: Don't do it by yourself. Use well tested [libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

Comment: Neither is your sample input valid JSON nor is it clear how your desired output relates to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for just convert JSON String to array string, you need to split the string with this code :

```
string jsonString= "{your json string}";
string[] MyObjects = jsonString.Split(',');
```

---

You can also parse it with JSON Parsers like NewtonJson or the default one!

```
var MyObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Any type you want> (jsonData);
```

OR Using JObject:

```
var MyObjects = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
```

Or Use Default one:

```
var MyObjects = (any type you want)serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
```

Comment: I want the text of the JSON object only, not the deserialized one.

Answer (score 0):

JsonUtility is a solution if you use Unity (otherwise you might find classes mentioned by Ali Kianoor useful). This could be a suitable data structure:

```
[Serializable]
class A
{
    public string name;
}

[Serializable]
class B {
    public List<A> list;
}
```

As your jsonRawText is not in the format of a standard json, let's just trim it as jsonText:

```
var jsonRawText = @"
    {
        ""name"": ""test 1"",
        ""value"": 123
    },
    {
        ""name"": ""test 2"",
        ""value"": 321
    }
";
var jsonText = "{\"list\": [" + jsonRawText + "]}";
var b = JsonUtility.FromJson<B>(jsonText);
```

And then copy strings in a list (if you wish):

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in b.list)
    list.Add(item.name);
```